# how could I verify authenticated user all the resource except session controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got an infinite loop by accessing the index with unauthenticated user

How could I get rid of it ? thanks

## error

```
Started GET "/sessions/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-20 18:24:58 +0800
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/sessions/new
Filter chain halted as :verify_authenticity rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
cache: [GET /sessions/new] miss
```

## Snippet

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :verify_authenticity, except: [:session]

  private
    def verify_authenticity
      redirect_to sessions_new_url unless current_user
    end
end


class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity

  def new
    redirect_to index_url if current_user
  end

end
```

Comment: I believe you have a custom implementation of `current_user`, could you show it ? Make sure it returns nil or false if there's no authenticated user, and not an actual object !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the way you check for authenticated user with

```
redirect_to index_url if current_user
```

I'd rather use a boolean method like `current_user?` or `user_logged_in?` that returns either true or false explicitely

Why ? Well, because in most applications, you still handle unauthenticated or guest login... with a User instance ! So, you ALWAYS have a `current_user` instance variable, but maybe with nil fields (like `login: nil`, `email: nil`).

Example of `current_user` authentication that completely thwarts your `if` condition:

```
def current_user
  if @current_user 
    return @current_user
  else
    @current_user = User.new
    @current_user.try_to_authenticate_with_params
  end
end
```

So basically, when you call

```
redirect_to index_url if current_user
```

It will always redirect, because `current_user` will return a User object, which is then interpreted as `true`

**So I suggest the following :**

```
class ApplicationController

    before_action :verify_authenticity

    def verify_authenticity
      # Your code
    end

    def user_signed_in?
      current_user.is_authenticated? # or whatever
    end
    alias :user_logged_in? :user_signed_in?

class SessionController < ApplicationController

    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity

    def new
      redirect_to index_url if user_signed_in?
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will try it  now. and did you mean `DO something if COND` is a bad style ? i didn't notice that, but i found it makes the code looks ugly although it saves words

Comment: Nono, `Do something if cond` is not a bad style at all, I use it a lot myself. On the contrary, I believe that's something you can only do in Ruby and it feels so natural to write it this way sometimes. At least, when dealing with very short/simple conditions and it can fit on a single line, like `redirect_to index_url if user_signed_in?`.